# Is the function `a -> <pattern> -> Bool` possible?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Would it be possible to have a function that takes some value and a pattern in order to check if both match?

Let's call this hypothetical function `matches` and with it we could rewrite the following function...

```hs
isSingleton :: [a] -> Bool
isSingleton [_] = True
isSingleton _   = False
```

...like so...

```hs
isSingleton xs = xs `matches` [_]
```

Would this be theoretically possible? If yes, how? And if not, why?

Comment: with template Haskell, yes.

Comment: If you don't mind using a different syntax then you can use [First Class Patterns](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.7006).

Comment: You can write `pattern Singleton <- [_]` with unidirectional `PatternSynonyms`. Maybe interesting to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't really use `[_]` as an expression – the compiler doesn't allow it. There are various bodges that could be applied to make it kind-of-possible:

- `-fdefer-typed-holes` makes GHC ignore the `_` during compilation. That doesn't really make it a legal expression, it just means the error will be raised at runtime instead. (Generally a very bad idea, should only be used for trying out something while another piece of your code isn't complete yet.)
- You could define `_' = undefined` to have similar syntax that is accepted as an expression. Of course, that still means there will be a runtime error.
- A runtime error could be caught, but only in the `IO` monad. That means basically *don't do anything that requires it*. But of course, technically speaking you could, and then wrap it in `unsafePerformIO`. Disgusting, but I won't say there aren't situations where this sort of thing is a necessary evil.

With that, you could already implement a function that would be able to determine that either it *definitely doesn't* match `[_]` (if `==` returns `False` without an error being raise), or *possibly matches* (in case the error is raised before a constructor discrepancy is found). That would be enough to determine that `[]` does not match `[_]`, but not to determine that `[1,_,3]` does not match `[1,_,0]`.

Again this could be botched around with a type class that first converts the values to a proper ⊥-less tree structure (using the `unsafePerformIO` catch to determine how deep to descent), but... please, let's stop the thought process here. We're clearly working against the language instead of with it with all of that.

What could of course be done is to do it in Template Haskell, but that would fix you to compile-time pattern expressions, I doubt that's in the spirit of the question. Or you could generate a type that explicitly expresses “original type with holes in it”, so the holes could properly be distinguished without any unsafe IO shenanigans. That would become quite verbose though.

In practice, I would just not try passing around first-class patterns, but instead pass around boolean-valued functions. Granted, functions are more general than patterns, but not in a way that would pose any practical problems.

Something that's more closely analogous to patterns are [`Prism`s in the `lens` ecosystem](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). Indeed, there is the [`is`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2/docs/Control-Lens-Extras.html#v:is) combinator that does what you're asking for. However, lenses/prisms can be again fiddly to construct, I'm not even sure a prism corresponding to `[_]` can be built using the `_Cons` and `_Empty` primitives.

**tl;dr** it's not worth it.

Comment: I believe `_Cons . aside _Empty` is the prism corresponding to `[_]`, but I'm not 100% sure (a quick QuickCheck test says yes but I'm honestly not well-versed in lens enough to say for sure). I still agree that it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Well thanks for that interesting deep dive! But where'd you get the impression from that compile-time pattern expressions wouldn't suffice? Before your answer I hadn't even considered constructing them at runtime.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride if you construct the patterns at compile-time, why do you need to pass them to a function then? Just put them in the function right there and then.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding? Looking at the 2nd block of example code in the question, would you agree that the pattern is constructed during compile-time there?

Comment: Sure, that is constructed during compile-time, but I took this for only a simplified example. After all, this particular example can and should instead be dealt with by implementing `isSingleton` in your first version, or `isSingleton = \case {[_] -> True; _ -> False}`.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns aren't first-class in Haskell; you cannot write a function that receives a pattern as an argument.

However, anywhere you would *call* your hypothetical `matches` function, you can instead make a bespoke function that tests the particular pattern you're interested in, and use that function instead. So you don't really *need* first class patterns, they just might save a bit of boilerplate.

The extension `LambdaCase` more or less allows you to write a function that *just* does a pattern match with minimal syntactic overhead, although there is no special-case syntax available for the specific purpose of returning a Bool saying whether a pattern matches (such special-purpose syntax would allow you to to avoid explicitly writing that you want to map the pattern to `True` and having to add a catch-all alternative case to map to `False`).

For example:

```
isSingleton = \case [_] -> True
                    _   -> False
```

For something like `isSingleton` (which already **is** a single pattern match encapsulated into a function) there's not much benefit in doing this over just implementing it directly. But in a more complex function whether you want to call `` x `matches` <pattern> `` (or pass `` (`matches` <pattern>) `` to another function), it might be an alternative that keeps the pattern inline.

Honestly I'd probably just define functions like `isSingleton` for each pattern I wanted this for though (possibly just in a `where` clause).